# How to create graphs from data from mssql database running on different computer on network?

Tags: sql-server, networking, graph

I am attempting to use PHP to connect to Microsoft SQL Database.  The PHP would need to retrieve data from table in database that is on a different computer in network.

From the retrieve data, a graph must be created.

Is there a better method of accomplishing this?

Comment: What's your actual question here, is something else better than PHP?

Comment: Have you looked at SSRS?